# Problems using screensaverdefaults

Tags: swift, screensaver

I want to save a variable defined from a dropdown in the preferences sheet to screensaverdefaults. Bools seem to save properly, but strings don't seem to save properly.
i tried `Database.standard.set(selectedVideo: "Choice")` where choice is a string. But something just doens't work right. I can upload the entire project if it can help me, i'm quite new to swift development.
Thanks in advance!

Added gists to some of the code:
https://gist.github.com/MaxTechnics/394bb98e88f526de5b93b50efdfa4bcf
https://gist.github.com/MaxTechnics/5527ede328595a63049e88ffa8f9c5f2

Comment: Please provide the code of Database.standard.set(selectedVideo: "Choice") and the code of method used for getting this string.

Comment: updated post with gists

Comment: You need to edit the question and add necessary code inside the question, not through external link. Please read how to provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in getter `selectedVideo`:

```
    var selectedVideo: String {
        return String(Database.Key.selectedVideo)
    }
```

This code just returns `Key`, not value.

It's necessary to use string accessor `UserDefaults.string(forKey:)`:

```
func string(forKey defaultName: String) -> String?
```

So the correct code should look like this:

```
    var selectedVideo: String? {
        return string(forKey: Database.Key.selectedVideo)
    }
```

or this:

```
    var selectedVideo: String {
        return string(forKey: Database.Key.selectedVideo) ?? "default value"
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was indeed the problem!